# Option to limit visibilty of users in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

Our main Azure DevOps Organization is linked to our Azure AD. We need to invite customers to specific projects as stakeholder only, and with this, they are added as external users in our AD. We found that within a customer project also, all other external users are visible, e.g. via mention with @ anywhere in the text or assignment drop-down, although these do not have access to that project. Our only workaround so far is to create new non AD linked customer specific organizations, but this is really not the right way to go (licencing, management etc.)

Is there any option to prevent this and to restrict visibility to only those users, which are part of a project (or planned)?

Answer (score 0):

I tested and found the same issue as you said. It is by design, you can raise a problem in the Developer Community
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html

Besides, since there is a workaround that works now, continue on this basis. You can create different AAD for the customer specific organizations, then add the customers to these AAD. Thus, these users will be invisible because they are in different AAD organizations.